# How Do I Calculate a "Call Level" Column on a DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame that could be thought of as a call stack, differentiated by a column, `Entry`, whose value is True when we enter the function and False when we leave. The other columns are `ThreadID` and `Function`, so that the data might look like this:

```
   ThreadID Function  Entry
0         1    FuncA   True
1         1    FuncB   True
2         1    FuncB  False
3         1    FuncC   True
4         1    FuncC  False
5         1    FuncA  False
```

and this represents something like this

```
FuncA() {
    FuncB();
    FuncC();
}
```

I would like to calculate an "call level" for each record based on the thread and function "depth." Iteratively, I would just look at each record, get the current call level for that thread, adjust it based on the value of `Entry` (add one for True, subtract one for False) and assign that value to the record as the `call_level` column.

*Note: This is a simplified version of my problem. The real problem also has other records that arent function entry/exit records, as if you added a log entry while you were in the function. I'd like to apply the current call level to those records, too.*

**This algorithm seems all wrong for Pandas.** Is there a better algorithm or way to think about solving this problem that would leverage vector operations and things that Pandas does well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.cumsum()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) to do the same thing as the iterative process you're describing, you just need to replace `False` with `-1` first, which we can do with [`.where()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html).

For the other records, I assume `Entry` is not applicable, so we'll replace NaN with `0`.

For handling each thread, we can use [`.groupby().transform()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html).

Finally we just need `.astype(int)` to convert `True` to `1`.

```
df['call_level'] = df.groupby('ThreadID')['Entry'].transform(
    lambda s: s.where(s, -1).where(s.notna(), 0).astype(int).cumsum()
)
```

```
   ThreadID Function  Entry  call_level
0         1    FuncA   True           1
1         1    FuncB   True           2
2         1    FuncB  False           1
3         1    FuncC   True           2
4         1    FuncC  False           1
5         1    FuncA  False           0
```

---

Here's an example with a non-function row and another thread:

```
   ThreadID Function  Entry  call_level
0         1    FuncA   True           1
1         1    FuncB   True           2
2         1      log    NaN           2
3         2        f   True           1
4         2        f  False           0
5         1    FuncB  False           1
6         1    FuncC   True           2
7         1    FuncC  False           1
8         1    FuncA  False           0
```

---

An alternative to `.where()` is [`np.select()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
...
    lambda s: np.select([s.isna(), s.astype(bool)], [0, 1], -1).cumsum()
```

Answer (score 2):

For your sample data, you can translate your `Entry` column into +/-1 by multiplying by 2 and subtracting 1; then you can simply take the cumulative sum to get the call level:

```
df['call_level'] = (df['Entry'] * 2 - 1).cumsum()
```

Output:

```
   ThreadID Function  Entry  call_level
0         1    FuncA   True           1
1         1    FuncB   True           2
2         1    FuncB  False           1
3         1    FuncC   True           2
4         1    FuncC  False           1
5         1    FuncA  False           0
```

If you have `None` or `nan` values in `Entry` where you are not entering/exiting a function, you can use `fillna` to set those to 0 so as not to change the call level on that row:

```
df['call_level'] = (df['Entry'] * 2 - 1).fillna(0).cumsum()
```

If you have multiple `ThreadID` values that you want to count separately, you can use `groupby`:

```
df['call_level'] = df.groupby('ThreadID')['Entry'].transform(lambda g:(g * 2 - 1).fillna(0).cumsum())
```